# jQuery BBQ pushState URL is not showing how it's supposed to

Tags: jquery, jquery-bbq

i am using the jQuery BBQ plugin, and I cant seem to show the url the way it's supposed to look. It comes like this, `/#url=photographs.php%3F1` were it's supposed to be `/#url=photographs.php?1`

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) which jQuery.bbq.pushState(state) does for you.

In your example, ?1 equals %3F1. You can see this by using a online URL [encode/decode tool](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/).

If you don't want this, try adding a hash symbol to your argument:

```
jQuery.bbq.pushState('#' + state);
```